# Как установить NodeJS через NVM?

Tags: node.js, npm, zsh, nvm

Я пытаюсь установить NodeJS последней версии и версии 10.13.0 через NVM в стандартном терминале на mac OS с оболочкой ZSH следующей командой:

```html
# nvm install stable
```

Команда начинает выполняться, но выходит ошибка:

```html
nvm install stable
mkdir: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin/.nvm/alias/lts: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin/.nvm/alias/lts: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin/.nvm/alias/lts: Permission denied
Downloading and installing node v12.5.0...
mkdir: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v12.5.0-darwin-x64/files: Permission denied
creating directory /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v12.5.0-darwin-x64/files failed
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.5.0/node-v12.5.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz...
Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/
Warning: bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v12.5.0-darwin-x64/node-
Warning: v12.5.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz: No such file or directory
                                                                           0,0%
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1057)
Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.5.0/node-v12.5.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz failed, trying source.
grep: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v12.5.0-darwin-x64/node-v12.5.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Clang v3.5+ detected! CC or CXX not specified, will use Clang as C/C++ compiler!
mkdir: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v12.5.0/files: Permission denied
creating directory /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v12.5.0/files failed
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.5.0/node-v12.5.0.tar.gz...
Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/
Warning: bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v12.5.0/node-v12.5.0.tar
Warning: .gz: No such file or directory
                                                                           0,0%
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1057)
Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.5.0/node-v12.5.0.tar.gz failed, trying source.
grep: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v12.5.0/node-v12.5.0.tar.gz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
```

Как устранить ошибку и установить обе версии?

Comment: у Вас пишет что нету прав на запись, попробуйте добавить sudo или какой у вас там аналог в маке? и второе действие, в ваш path нужно добавить nodejs, так как бывает что из-за этого он его не видит.

Comment: я бы на вашем бы месте использовал не nvm а vagrant что бы четко разделять где какая версия.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло только полное удаление NVM и Node.js, установка XCode и после этого запуск команды

```html
 
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```